# Jersey WebApplicationException and servlet filters

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

In my application, I throw WebApplicationExceptions for exception cases so that I can pass back nice messages with my 500s.  The problem I am running into is that I have a servlet filter for hibernate transactions and have noticed that the WebApplicationException is being trapped before it comes back to the servlet filter.  I have included a brief version of my servlet filter as an example.  Note: I only have one other servlet filter which does authentication and has no catches

```
    try {
        em = MauiPersistenceUtil.getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        // raises WebApplicationException
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

        // since WebApplicationException is trapped somewhere else up 
        // the filterChain bad data is committed here
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // I want the WebApplicationException to reach here
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
```

Thanks,
Ransom

Edit: Ryan Stewart pointed out that I did not actually ask a question.  My question is: How can I tell in a servlet filter that a web application exception was thrown down in the filterChain?  I was expecting that Jersey would rethrow the exception, but that was incorrect.

Comment: Another possibility is described  http://markmail.org/thread/orcctyu7hczx3d5w#query:+page:1+mid:orcctyu7hczx3d5w+state:results that also sounds feasible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you didn't ask a specific question, I'll make some observations.

1. You should use declarative transactions, such as those provided by Spring, instead of trying to manage them yourself in this way, exactly because you'll run into problems like this.
2. Similar to 1., I very much doubt you will want to roll back transactions on all exceptions. Again, look into a framework to help you with this.
3. A WebApplicationException is intercepted and handled by Jersey. Presumably you're running Jersey in the standard way, as a servlet. Filters execute around servlets. Therefore the Jersey servlet handles the exception before it makes it out the filter.

Comment: I guess I just expected Jersey to rethrow the exception.  That would also allow me to log these in another filter.

Comment: The [Jersey User Guide](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e441) talks about the WebApplicationException. It exists specifically so that you can throw exceptions that Jersey will translate to appropriate responses for you. If you don't want that, then you need to throw anything but a WebApplicationException.

Comment: Taking Ryan Stewart's suggestion and throwing anything but a WebApplicationException.  This way I can map things the way I want in servlet filters.

Answer (score 1):

You should inspect the response status after "doFilter":

```
 filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);

 Integer status = ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).getStatus();
 if (HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.equals(status) {
     em.getTransaction().rollback();
 } else {
     em.getTransaction().commit();
 }
```

If Status is 500 then rollback, as simple as that. You will never get WebApplicationException on Servlet filters, they are catched by Jersey Servlet.